# How to export data (which is as result of Python program) from command line?

Tags: python, export-to-excel

I am working on a Python program, and I have results on the command line.

Now I need to do analysis on the results, so I need all results as exported in any format like either SQL, or Excel or CSV format.

Can some tell me how can i do that ?

```
import csv
x1=1 x2=2
while True:
    show = [ dict(x1=x1+1 , x2=x2+2)]
    print('Received', show )
    with open('large1.csv','w') as f1:
        writer=csv.writer(f1, delimiter=' ',lineterminator='\n\n',)
        writer.writerow(show)
    x1=x1+1
    x2=x2+1
```

Here this is infinite loop and I want to have a csv file containing 2 column of x1 and x2. and with regularly updated all values of x1 and x2 row wise (1 row for 1 iteration)

But by this code I'm getting a csv file which is named as 'large1.csv' and containing only one row (last updated values of x1 and x2).

So how can I get my all values of x1 and x2 as row was in python.

Comment: In order to help you, we should know the data you want to extract and in waht format. Also, please post a piece of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the csv format it can easily imported into Excel and
the python standard library supports csv out of the box. @See [python-csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Comment: Thank you Nicoretii. i m trying it now and let you know the results.

Comment: i added my code. and i m using csv module but still couldnt get result as per required

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle this is to use the [CSV module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv), and specifically a [Writer object](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects) to write the output to a CSV file (perhaps even instead of writing to `stdout`). The documentation has several examples, including this one:

```
import csv
with open('some.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(someiterable)
```

You should then be able to import the CSV file easily in Excel if that is what you want.

Comment: my Sample Code:
import csv
x1=1 x2=2
while True: 
   show = [ dict (x1=x1+1 , x2=x2+2)]  
   print('Received', show ) 
   with open('large1.csv','w') as f1: 
       writer=csv.writer(f1, delimiter=' ',lineterminator='\n\n',) 
       writer.writerow( show ) 
   x1=x1+1 
   x2=x2+1

Comment: here this is infinite loop and i want to have a csv file containig 2 column of x1 and x2. and with regularly updated all values of x1 and x2 row wise (1 row for 1 iteration) 

but by this code im getting csv file which is named as 'large1.csv' and containing only one row (last updated values of x1 and x2).
So how can i get my all values of x1 and x2 as row was in python.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [open() documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open).

Mode `w` will *truncate* the file, which means it will replace the contents. Since you call that every loop iteration, you are continuously deleting the file and replacing it with a new one. Mode `a` appends to the file and is *maybe* what you want. You also might consider opening the file outside of the loop, in that case `w` might be the correct mode.